# custom default value for added column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration, default-value

I am creating a migration in which I add a column to the model. Since there are already objects in the model, I want to give them a default value. But the meaning for different objects will be different depending on the state of another object in the linked model.

```
class Message < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :user
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
 has_many :messages
end

class AddColumnMessageSendType < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    add_column :mesasges, :send_type, :string, default: ???
  end
end
```

Can be added `each do` after  `def change` and do `update(send_type: custom_value)` by using `if` or do it in a new migration. But I'm wondering if you can use the `default:` for this. Thanks

Comment: The default does what it says, it is a predefined string, no way to reference anything from there.

Answer (score 0):

I'd create a callback to deal with this for new records moving forward and incorporate a rake task for the already existing ones.

app/models/message.rb:

```
class Message < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user

  before_create :set_send_type

  def set_send_type
    if something
      send_type = 'a'
    else
      send_type = 'b'
    end
  end
end
```

The above will run every time you create a new message. There's a lot more on callbacks [here](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html).

Then in a rake task (lib/tasks/set_send_types.rake):

```
rake set_send_types: :environment do
  Message.all.each do |message|
    message.set_send_type
    message.save
  end
end
```

You'd need to call the `message.save` in the rake task because the `set_send_type` in this example doesn't actually save to the DB itself. It relies on the saving that happens after running the callback.

You should only need to run the rake task once.